# How to parse the queryset from django-simple-history?

Tags: django, django-views, django-simple-history

How to parse the queryset from the django-simple-history to a html table with columns: history_id, history_date and etc. I'm inherit DetailView class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example form django-simple-history:

```
from django.db import models
from simple_history.models import HistoricalRecords

class Poll(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    history = HistoricalRecords()

class Choice(models.Model):
    poll = models.ForeignKey(Poll)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    history = HistoricalRecords()
```

now you can access history by:

```
all_history = poll.history.all()
```

more info :

1. https://django-simple-history.readthedocs.io/en/latest/querying_history.html
2. https://django-simple-history.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quick_start.html